# Magento 1.7 Shopping cart rule, category not obeyed when config product in cart

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

Let's keep it simple, I have the following categories:

*Caps (ID: 1)
Accessorries (ID:2)*

I have the following rule:

*"Any 3 caps , 10% OFF (discount applied to caps only)"*

And now I have the following items in the cart with the following results:

1. 3 caps (3 Simple Products) - Rule runs - Expected
2. 2 caps (2 Simple Products) and 1 Accessory (simple) - Rule Does not run - Expected
3. 2 caps (1 Simple Product + 1 Config Product) and 1 Accessory (simple) - Rule Runs - **NOT Expected**
4. 2 caps (1 Simple Product + 1 Config Product) - Rule does not run - Expected

As you can see in the above third scenario, there are 3 items in the cart. However, the shopping cart price rule does not obey categories when a configurable product (cap) was added to the cart.

This is for Magento 1.702 and I have done a diff compare of core files and there are no differences. Was wondering if anyone could reproduce the above or have a solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the accessory in case 3 is not placed in both categories? Just asking to get that out of the way. Also did you rebuild your indexes?

Comment: Hi Marius, its definite that the accessory in case 3 was not placed in both categories. In fact, the accessory above was just an example, it could be any other simple product from a different category - bag, shoe, etc.